# How to handle when a page has many GridView/ListView vertically in uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

When a page has many `GridView`/`ListViews` vertically, we have to use a `ScrollViewer` to scroll up/down. But a `ScrollViewer` will destroy `GridView`/`ListView`'s UI virtualization, this result a huge cpu and memory usage.

But uwp doesn't provide a pure ScrollViewer, which just scroll up/down/left/right, and does't detroy `GridView`/`ListView`'s UI virtualization.

So how to handle this sutuation?

Comment: 2 case: 1st, a page has a `GridView`/`ListView`, each `ListViewItem` template is a `GridView`/`ListView`, like NetFlix layout. 2nd, just many `GridView`/`ListView`s layout in one page.

Answer (score 0):

> But a ScrollViewer will destroy GridView/ListView's UI virtualization, this result a huge cpu and memory usage.

There are many way could approach, You could create [`Pivot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/pivot) to place each `GridView`. and use paging data to reduce memory and CPU usage.

```
<Pivot Title="EMAIL">
    <PivotItem Header="All">
        <TextBlock Text="all emails go here." />
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Unread">
        <TextBlock Text="unread emails go here." />
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Flagged">
        <TextBlock Text="flagged emails go here." />
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Urgent">
        <TextBlock Text="urgent emails go here." />
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

And you also use `Blade` that comes Community Tool Kit nuget package. Base on your data model to create multiple Blade that place the `GridView` or `ListView`.

```
<controls:BladeItem x:Name="SecondBlade"
                          Header="Default blade"
                          IsOpen="False"
                          Style="{StaticResource BladeStyle}">
        <TextBlock Margin="24"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Style="{StaticResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"
                   Text="This is a blade with all settings set to default." />
</controls:BladeItem>
```

For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.bladeview?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable).